# why filename will return nil in alamo fire uploading images in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, filenames, image-uploading

I want to upload multipart images in my project with alamo fire some times with no reason the alamo fire file name will return nil - how can I avoid that ?

```
let params: Parameters = ["name": "image\(i)"]
                    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
                        {

                            (multipartFormData) in
                            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageUploadingViewController.imageUpload[i], 1.0)!, withName: "myfile", fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                            for (key, value) in params
                            {
                                multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)

                            }
                    }, to: "http:example.com/api/file?api_token=\(enterViewController.api_token)&id=\(self.postID)",headers:nil)
                    { (result) in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let upload,_,_ ):
                            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                                UploadingViewController.progressing = progress.fractionCompleted

                                self.UpdateState()


                                if progress.fractionCompleted == 1.0 {


                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                        UploadingViewController.fine = UploadingViewController.fine + 1

                                    }


                                    print(UploadingViewController.fine)
                                    self.checkUploadProgress()
                                    print("OK Finished!")

                                }


                            })
```

the application will crash in this line because of fileName

```
multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UploadingImagesViewController.imageUpload[i], 1.0)!, withName: "myfile", fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

remember that some times it will work I don't know why this will happen!

Comment: are you set header an to value in upload function ?

Comment: yes wait please I will add it to my codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func sendImageToServerWithURL(_ URLString: URLConvertible, method: HTTPMethod, headers: [String : String]?, parameters: [String: Any]?, imageData : Data?,imageName:String,completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        if((imageData) != nil)
        {
             multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName:imageName, fileName: "swift_file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }

        for (key, value) in parameters!
        {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, to:URLString ,headers : headers)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                //Print progress
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print (response.result)

                completionHandler(response)
            }

        case .failure( _): break
            //print encodingError.description
        }
    }
}
```

i am using the method  to upload pic . i check **if((imageData) != nil)** the data value before upload . may be this helpful.

Comment: the app doesn't let me to run because of CompletionHandler

Comment: you need to check (value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!  data value before using

Comment: I used that and when image data is nil this will return using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!  but when I upload image to the server the server just show me the text file

Comment: you only need to check image data value not nil . you are using UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageUploadingViewController.imageUpload[i] to get imagedata value. if image data value not nil and your server sending text file it's sever side issue.

Comment: it will work but not properly some times some images won't upload but after I used your codes there is no crash thanks

Comment: again I received that error it still doesn't fixed :(